# Data folder on different drive - Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am about to install PostgreSQL for the first time. I am brand new to it and very much a beginner in this area. I am using Windows 7. I would like to install PostgreSQL 9.4 on the default C: and would like to have all databases be created on the D:

Please can someone advise how to accomplish this so that when I start creating databases, they will be on the D:

Thanks.

Comment: Just tell `initdb` to create the data folder on a different disk (I haven't used the GUI installer for ages, so I don't really know in which step it does that, and if you can change it all)

Comment: You could use the default installation and afterwards create a new tablespace. Set this tablespace as your new default, and all new objects will be created at this location.

Comment: @FrankHeikens Not a great idea... it means that losing *either* disk will lose *all* their data. Do not use a tablespace for this. Move the datadir.